# Kendo tree list two way data binding angular js

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, treelist, kendo-treelist

I have to create the kendo ui tree list with two way data binding. I have try with the kendo grid which is working but for kendo tree list it is not working. Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Kendo grid example :-  http://dojo.telerik.com/OvUxU/2

Kendo tree list example :- http://dojo.telerik.com/@vinay/arAwo

Answer (score 0):

The TreeList is a bit different in this behavior due to how it process data related to load-on-demand. In order make this scenario work you should defined dataSource.data instead of directly dataSource as array.

Here is the updated example - http://dojo.telerik.com/@rusev/oJeho